# Decoding Url with c# in .NET4 Client profile

Tags: c#, .net-client-profile

How to decode URL in .NET 4 Client Profile?
HttpUtil is not accessible from this profile...Maybe some opensource libs?Or maybe some way to add HttpUtil without changing target framework?

Comment: why are you restricted to .NET client profile? Just switch to full .NET 4, it's not that much bigger anyway.

Comment: Project is a part of very big solution, I'm not sure I have to switch to .NET 4 Full only because of this small problem...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx).

Comment: Great, thanks! I am wondering why I was unable to find it...Every time I googled  - I saw  only HttpUtil...

Comment: Now your question will show up in Google result for others to find ;)

Comment: I hope) Sometimes solutions are so simple)

Answer (score 1):

Is [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) any use to you?